# When I hit the breakpoint (1200px) my layout is broken

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, breakpoints

I have made a breakpoint at 1200px (when users minimise the browser window) however when the content hits 1200px there is a blank space left. I would like this to be filled with the other content on my page at the global width disclosed in my CSS at 80%. My current format works across all of my other pages and screen widths except this one.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>DB Plumbing | About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a2264e344.js"></script>
  <script src="html9shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="wrench.png"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="desciption" content = "Darran Brady Plumbing">
  <meta name="keywords" content = "Plumbing, Boilers, Showers, Central Heating, Kitchens, Bathrooms, Installations, Landlord Services, Horsham, West Sussex, Sussex,Barns Green, Billingshurst,Broadbridge Heath,Christ's Hospital, Clemsfold, Copsale,Colgate,Cowfold, Faygate, Handcross, Horsham, Itchingfield, Kingsfold,Lambs Farm,Lower Beeding,Mannings Heath, Maplehurst, Monks Gate, Nuthurst, Partridge Green, Pease Pottage, Roffey, Rowhook, Rusper, Rudgwick, Southwater, Slinfold, Warnham ">
  <meta name = "author" content ="DB, Darran, Brady, Darran Brady">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 if (x.className === "topnav") {
 x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
 x.className = "topnav";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:140%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </header>

<div class="container">
      <div class="dark">
            <div class="callus"><a href="tel:+07756848657"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x" ></i></a></div>
 <h2>Our Story</h2>
            </div>
            </div>

<section id="main">
      <div class="container">

        <article id="main-col">
          <p>
            Our customer's individual requirements are important to us at DB Plumbing. We always provide quality service and products and combined with honesty has made us the first choice of many homes in the Horsham area.</p>

<div class="dark">

          <h3>What We Offer</h3>
            <ul>
            <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Gas Safe Registered: 202542</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>25 years of expertise</li> <li>Plumbing and Heating Services</li>
            <li>Heating Engineer Qualified</li>
            <li>VAT Registered</li>
            <li>100% Satisfaction Garauntee</li>
            </ul>  
        </article>

        <aside id="sidebar">
          <div class="dark">
          <p>"98% Customer Satisfaction"</p>
           <a href="http://www.checkatrade.com/DBPlumbing/Reviews.aspx"><img class="catsmall" src="cat.png" alt="checkatradelogo" ></a>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>
 <footer>
    <div>
      <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
      <p>Registered in England No. 4364232</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS (shortened, from media q)

```
*minimised browser winddow */
@media(max-width: 1150px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  aside#sidebar{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
  }

main{
  width: 80%;
}







/* 768 tablet */
@media(max-width: 768px){
  header #branding,
  header nav,
  header nav li,
  #newsletter h1,
  #newsletter form,
  #boxes .box,
  article#main-col,
  aside#sidebar{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
  }

  header{
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }

#imagery {
  display: none;
}

  #showcase h1{
    font-size: 275%;  
  }

  #showcase p{
    font-size: 100%;
  }

  #newsletter button, .quote button{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }

  #newsletter form input[type="email"], .quote input, .quote textarea{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }

.col-25, .col-75 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}


  /* nav */
 ul.topnav li {
  display: none;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
 display: inline-block;
 }


ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
 ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li {
 float: none;   /*  'un' float the list items so they return to displaying vertically */
 display: inline;
 }
 ul.topnav.responsive li a {
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 }
}




/* 400 pixels mobile phone */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  header #branding, header nav, header nav li {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100%
  }
  header ul{
  padding:10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  }

#social {
  font-size: 150%;
}



#imagery .box{
  size: 10px 10px;
```

}

Comment: There is no such CSS property as `size`..what is that meant to be?

Comment: The top comment in your css is broken